# Error reporting for php docker in browser

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I am facing an issue where I am trying to run a docker container to practice php on local. When I hit the index php page in the browser after spinning up the container, it does not report error for me when there is an error. It just shows a white screen.

My docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tcl locales \
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y nginx curl zip unzip git software-properties-common supervisor \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.4-fpm php7.4-cli php7.4-gd php7.4-mysql \
        php7.4-imap php7.4-imagick php7.4-opcache php7.4-mbstring php7.4-xml php7.4-zip php7.4-intl php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-curl \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && mkdir /run/php \
    && apt-get remove -y --purge software-properties-common \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

COPY default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

COPY php-fpm.conf /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf

EXPOSE 88

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Now to report the error please assist in what could be done to fix it?

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff that's surely not necessary to demonstrate the problem. Also, it's not clear what you would expect and why! Please extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Run `docker logs -f your_container_name` and refresh web browser to see what error do you see in docker logs.

Comment: I am want to report php errors in the browser. So for example if there is an syntax error. I want to display it in the browser.

Comment: You should run `php -i | grep -i ini` to see where is your `php.ini` file, and change `display_errors` to `On` if there are any errors or warnings.